# Trying to use appcenter Distribute in Android

Tags: android, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

Hello all I followed the guide

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/distribute/android

```
 AppCenter.start(getApplication(), "real app secret ", Distribute.class);
 Log.e("Distribute","start worked for Dist without listener");
```

I am doing this in an onCreate of a library that does the login for my application and i see the log being printed yet no dialog pops up

Any ideas what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you implemented a custom listener? It should extend from the below interface. I have provided an example of what I have that works for me!

```
Distribute.setListener(new AppCenterUpdateListener());
Distribute.setEnabled(true);
AppCenter.start(getApplication(),"secret", Distribute.class);


class AppCenterUpdateListener : DistributeListener {

override fun onReleaseAvailable(activity: Activity, releaseDetails: ReleaseDetails): Boolean {
    // Look at releaseDetails public methods to get version information, release notes text or release notes URL
    val versionName = releaseDetails.shortVersion
    val versionCode = releaseDetails.version
    val releaseNotes = releaseDetails.releaseNotes
    val releaseNotesUrl = releaseDetails.releaseNotesUrl

    // Build our own dialog title and message
    val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity, R.style.alertDialogNoBar)
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Version $versionName available!")
    dialogBuilder.setMessage(releaseNotes)

    // Mimic default SDK buttons
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(com.microsoft.appcenter.distribute.R.string.appcenter_distribute_update_dialog_download) { _,_ ->
        Distribute.notifyUpdateAction(UpdateAction.UPDATE)
    }

    // We can postpone the release only if the update is not mandatory
    if (!releaseDetails.isMandatoryUpdate) {
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(com.microsoft.appcenter.distribute.R.string.appcenter_distribute_update_dialog_postpone) { _,_ ->
            Distribute.notifyUpdateAction(UpdateAction.POSTPONE)
        }
    }
    dialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
    dialogBuilder.create().show()

    // Return true if you are using your own dialog, false otherwise
    return true
}
```

}